# storing mysql query result in session in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

This is my code in controller...

```
function get_product(){
        $purchase_id=$_POST['purchase_id'];
        if($purchase_id!=''){
        //$post_array['cart']='';
        $res = $this->db->query("select * from phppos_productdetails WHERE
  purchase_id='$purchase_id'");
        ?>
        <tr>
<th>Product  Name</th>
<th>Quantity </th>
<th>Unit </th>
<th>Unit Rate</th>
<th>Action</th>
</tr>
        <?php
 $i=0;
        foreach($res->result() as $row )
        {
            $sess_products[$i]['product_id'] = $row->product_id;
        $sess_products[$i]['quantity'] = $row->quantity;
        $sess_products[$i]['unit'] = $row->unit;
        $sess_products[$i]['unit_rate'] = $row->unit_rate;

        $this->session->set_userdata('sess_products',$sess_products);

        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT product_name FROM phppos_product WHERE 
  product_id='".$row->product_id."'");
    foreach ($query->result() as $row1 )
{
$product_name=$row1->product_name;

}
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$product_name."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row->quantity."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row->unit."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row->unit_rate."</td>";
    echo "<td><a href='javascript:void(0)' rownum='".$i."' class='remove_from_cart'><img src='images/close.png'/></a></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    $i++;

        }


    }
}
```

This is function in controller that is being called by ajax call. So how do I store that query result in session array in codeigniter??

I am acessing like this

```
 $demo_arr['cart']= $this->session->userdata('sess_products');
```

Comment: What you mean by store to the session array ? `$data = ['a' => 'b', 'c' => 'd']; $this->session->set_userdata($data);` access it anywhere via `$this->session->userdata('a');` if this what you asking for.

Comment: @Nucleo1985 see my edit above..after foreach code

Comment: You have to set the session data first via `$this->session->set_userdata(whatever here)` did you set this already ?

Comment: @Nucleo1985 See my edited code...I am setting it there in foreach loop

Comment: you set it on wrong way, `$data = array('product_id' => $row->product_id etc etc);` then you can set `$this->session->set_userdata($data)` not like how you set above. Assuming this `$demo_arr['cart']= $this->session->userdata('sess_products');` is correct way, so what the var_dump of this `$demo_arr['cart']` ?

Comment: @Nucleo1985 when  var_dump it, it display bool(false)

Comment: so thats it, its have no value. for make sure, what the result of this `$this->session->userdata('sess_products');` ? try to set like i told you.

Comment: Sry..it's my mistake ...it has value..But when i var_dump it.it displays...array(4) {
  ["product_id"]=>
  string(1) "9"
  ["quantity"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["unit"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["unit_rate"]=>
  string(3) "100"
}

Comment: So loop it and access it via the declared variable. What else, its an array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68198/discussion-between-kedar-b-and-nucleo-1985).